# Why use Enterprise App+Web app on Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I didn't know what title use here, 'cause I'm really confused about Java EE. I'm trying to learn it for a school project but I can hardly understand Java EE architecture. I've seen some youtube tutorials to create web app projects on NetBeans+Glassfish, but they all are just web applications. I've seen a guy in school creating an Enterprise App and then a Web App, he enabled context dependency and dependency injection, and added the web app to the enterprise app. What is the purpose of that? (considering that my assignment is to make a mini bank system, with a web app and an ATM-desktop app). If I do that, can I still follow the youtube-web-app tutorials?

Thanks, and sorry for this vague question, but I'm really lost.

Answer (score 0):

There are many advantages of Java Enterprise applications like implements best practices and most of important design patterns.

but first of all if you did not know your problems and your system complexity, you will not get that advantages.

My advice to you is to start creating a simple web application and add features and framework in your go.

The following link provide a netbeans tutorial for Java web and enterprise application using netbeans IDE that may help you

[Java EE & Java Web Learning Trail](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html)